# How to Download an Image and save it on sd card in blackberry 5.0

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am developing one application in which i download one image from URL , now i want to save that image on SD card. Can anyone please help me by providing me the code to achieve this ?

Comment: duplicate ! make a search by typing `download` in the search field at the upper right corner of this site !

Comment: To filter your search to a specific tag type like this in the field : `[java-me] download` then press the "Enter" keyboard key.

Answer (score 0):

For the `SD Card` question **only** take a look at ["Getting Started with the FileConnection APIs"](http://developers.sun.com/mobility/apis/articles/fileconnection/).